# NSSplitViewItem does not display like it designed in IB

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nssplitview

I created a new empty Xcode project. And just added a NSSplitViewController to storyboard like below.

[image]

And I ran the application, found out that the main window looked like below.

[image]

The left split view was collapsed by default. I hoped it should be displayed like below:

[image]

And I was not set both split view item's collapsed property in Xcode.

Any one could help me to figure out what's wrong with my app?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try connecting the `view` outlet of the `NSSplitViewController` to the `NSSplitView` - this worked for me in a simple sample project. [image]

If no-one comes along with a better answer, I'd consider filing this behaviour as a bug using Apple's *Bug Reporter* - either this connection should be configured by default, or it shouldn't be needed at all.